# Disable auto-reconnect

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, openvpn

I am using AWS VPN endpoint, and open vpn client. From aws cli I can trigger disconnection of every client, however openvpn reconnects all automatically. How could I disable that? In options manual I found only "connection retry time". These are my options:

```
client

dev tun

proto udp

remote-random-hostname

resolv-retry infinite

nobind

auth-nocache

remote-cert-tls server

cipher AES-256-GCM

verb 3
```

Removing resolv-retry infinite does not solve the problem.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? I have a big problem in that an entire department simply leaves the VPN connected and then goes to Cabo for the weekend, resulting in unnecessary usage costs. I would preferably like to automatically disconnect, but I'm finding that the client simply reconnects them automatically :'( i tried resetting the client to `resolv-retry 0` and that didn't solve the problem either.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon see my answer below, it may help as a mitigation

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but you can define an `inactive` setting in the .ovpn file that disconnects the VPN client on the client side if inactivity is detected. Then the user should need to manually reconnect.

Format is `inactive n [bytes]`, e.g. for a timeout after 10 minutes with less than 1000 bytes of activity, you'd use:

```
inactive 600 [1000]
```

The `[bytes]` portion is optional, but gives you some leeway on "how active" someone needs to be to maintain a connection.

Found this documented in the [OpenVPN docs](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/) in the section on "--inactive" setting.